# foreignkey backwards manager not working django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

This seems simple.. I have a `Restaurant` model and `Recipe` model, all I want is to be able to look up all the `Recipes` by a certain `Restaurant`. I am using the backwards manager FOO_set and cant seem to make it work:

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')

class Recipe(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipe')
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        user.restaurant
        recipe_list = user.restaurant.recipe_set
        return render(request, 'usermanage/dashboard_restaurant.html',{'recipe_list':recipe_list})
```

When i run this i get an exception in the `dashboard` view. Looking at my database the user.restaurant object has recipes associated with it. If i just do `recipe_list = user.restaurant` it returns the restaurant object. Just when I add `recipe_set` it fails. Also tried `recipe_set.all` and `all()`. I have migrated everything. Django 1.11

Comment: always include the full traceback of the error in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set `related_name` so you need to use it:
replace:

```
recipe_list = user.restaurant.recipe_set
#                                   ^^^^^
```

to

```
recipe_list = user.restaurant.recipe.all()
#                                ^^^^^^
```